# Is there any source of information about car models and brands in which it is possible to know the fuel level through the OBDII PID 2F?

Tags: obd-ii, fuel-consumption, fuel-tank, pid

Although OBDII has been mandatory since 1996 for North American vehicles and manufacturers must respect generic fault codes and that OBDII defines a series of PID commands to know the status of many vehicle operation variables, I have not found ( there may or may not exist) some reliable source of information reporting the use of these (non-mandatory) PIDs in different brands and models of cars.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're asking, because 2F is the PID used to bring back the fuel level which is exactly what you're asking for? It should provide a number between 0 and 100 (empty and full). I guess you can think of it as a percentage.

According to [this Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs):

> SAE standard J1979 defines many OBD-II PIDs. All on-road vehicles and trucks sold in North America are required to support a subset of these codes, primarily for state mandated emissions inspections. Manufacturers also define additional PIDs specific to their vehicles.

All of the PIDs listed on the Wiki page should be generic to ***all*** vehicles in North America. 2F is among those codes. If you're looking at NA vehicles listing, just take your pick. They should all be using the same PID.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that the PID's are not mandatory. Each manufacturer may or may not implement them in their different models. For example, PID 2F is not responding on several Nissan models. And this happens for other brands. This is why I am looking to get (eventually buy) a reliable listing. Best Regards.

Comment: And you'd be wrong. The "generic" pids are mandatory in order for the OBDII system (to include the CANBus) to work correctly. It's called a "standard". If you send out a request through the CANBus for the PID 2F, you can expect the fuel level to be returned.